# confusion over setTimeout and clearTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I have a button that changes the background of a div when its rolled over. the background needs to change on a timer so i have used setTimout to execute methods that change the backgrounds. I thought clearTimeout would cancel and timeouts i have set so i put this on the mouseleave event. However it doesnt seem to stop the timeouts. Is my logic right here?

```
$("#h2Buzz").mouseenter(function () {   
   setTimeout(playV(), 2700);
   setTimeout(playP(), 5400);
}); 
$("#h2Buzz").mouseleave(function () {
   clearTimeout(playV());
   clearTimeout(playP());
});


function playV() {
    $("#ServicesBackgroundImage2").css("background-image", "url(/images/v.jpg)");
}
function playPn() {

    $("#ServicesBackgroundImage2").css("background-image", "url(/images/p.jpg)");
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assign a variable to your `setTimeout`, which you then pass to `clearTimeout` to clear it, i.e.

```
var play_timeout = setTimeout("playV()", 2700);
clearTimeout(play_timeout);
```

(Note I added quotes around your first `setTimeout` argument)

Comment: No need to use quotes, just pass the function name: `var play_timeout = setTimeout(playV, 2700);
`

Answer (score 7):

You are using `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout` wrongly. The `setTimeout` function returns a handle to the timeout, which is to be passed into `clearTimeout` to stop it.

```
var playVTimeout;

...

    playVTimeout = setTimeout(playV, 2700);

....

    clearTImeout(playVTimeout);
```

Also note that `setTimeout(playV(), 2700);` will call `playV()` *now* and execute its return value 2.7 seconds later. You should pass a function object `playV` in instead.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `setTimeout`, it returns a numeric value. You should store this value, because this is what you need for clearTimeout. So keep track of the return value from both setTimeout's (they will be different). And keep track of them in a scope you can access from both functions.

Quick 'n' Dirty Example:

```
var timer = setTimeout( function(){ alert('hi'); }, 300 );
clearTimeout( timer );
```

Also, you are calling setTimeout with 'playV()', this is incorrect as it will immediately call that function this way. You can leave the brackets behind, so just `setTimeout( playV, 3500 );`